# WordPress make all post types and taxonomies work on paged index

Tags: php, wordpress

In my index.php file have the following query to loop through posts while paginating them.

```
$posts_per_page = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_status'=>'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'paged' => $paged,
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);


// The loop 
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

    the_title();

endwhile; endif;
```

It works great but for example when I try to view a taxonomy belonging  to a custom post type `mysite.com/custom-taxonomy`, it still loops normal blog posts instead of the custom post type.

How can I make index.php show posts whether they are normal blog posts, custom post types, custom taxonomy, or custom terms? Without creating separate `archive-taxonomy` files.

It seems redundant to create a new file for each taxonomy/post type/term when using the same HTML for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use tax_query in your loop for custom taxonomy as shown below:

$args = array(
    'post_status'=>'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'taxonomy' => 'your_taxonomy',
        'terms' => 'if any',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'operator' => 'IN'
         ),
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```